# Add image to Wordpress Header

Tags: php, image, wordpress, header

I’m using Wordpress to set up a content managed website and I’m fairly competent with HTML and CSS. I can change the background image of the site in the CSS and can change the header image (background).

What I want to do is add an image within the header which I can position absolutely. However, when I try to add an image with the  tag into the header.php, it shows the ‘broken image’ icon, even though I am typing the code correctly.

If I add a div, I can set a background image, but it resizes it all oddly and doesn’t look right.

I'm using the Wordpress TwentyEleven or TwentyTen theme and just cannot figure this out. I presume it's some limitation of Wordpress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you're doing? WordPress themes should be able to display any image, there's no limitation there.

Comment: Can you link to the site? Much easier to trouble shoot then :)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using or provide a link to the project in question.  if you are getting a broken image icon there is liekly something wrong with the path to the image.

Comment: Where exactly is the image located? There are many ways to define the correct path: bloginfo(), site_url(), ABSPATH, TEMPLATEPATH, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it does not work directly in header.php and works as a background for a div means (although you are not showing your code, and you should) that you are probably using relative links. The problem is that the inclusion of template parts in WordPress makes the use of relative links more difficult. 
However, if you use a div, you shouldn't have any problem and the background image shouldn't resize (if the CSS rule is correctly defined). 
But solving a path problem by inserting a div is bad practice. Just use absolute path to your image (or at least relative to the website root, like `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/yourimage.png`).
However, please post your code (the img tag and/or the CSS rule for the div).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting the URL for the image wrong.  You can use relative paths safely in the stylesheet because all URLs in there are relative to the location of style.css (generally your wp-content/themes/yourtheme directory).  However this is not the case if you call an image in header.php - the relative path will change based on the URL of the page that is loaded (it will just add whatever is in the SRC attribute of the img element on to whatever the URL is).

You can get around this by either specifying an absolute path (e.g. http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/images/yourimage.jpg) OR by using a WP template tag that gets your stylesheet directory and add that to the img SRC attribute like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/yourimage.png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/logo2.png"/>
```

****This worked for me****